# Show $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$ (assume $f(X)=Y$)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two nonempty sets and consider a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$. Show that if $B \subseteq Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$.

**But, with the addition assumption that $f(X)=Y$.**

I recently made a similar post with this exercise, with some pointed out that the claim was false. But it is perhaps right with this additional assumption.

This is my attempt:

Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. Then, since $y=f(x)$, $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. But the inverse images are defined for all functions, so $y \in B$.
Conversely, let $y \in B$. Then there is a $x \in f^{-1}(B)$ so that $f(x)=y$, and hence a $y \in f(f^{-1}(B))$.

I don't know if this is correctly (?), but, it seemed easier under the additional assumption. I find "proof based techniques" more challenging than "numbers".

Here we also have the difference between inverse images, with are defined for all functions, and the inverse functions, with requires the function to be bijective. Making the assumption that $f(X)=Y$ is making assumptions about $f$ being surjective, as I understand it. But if we also did make assumption that $f$ is injective, $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ would been obvious because the composition would cancel the terms.

But, I'd appreciate some feedback to the correctness of my math here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes, $f(X) = Y$ means exactly that $f$ is surjective.

About the proof, it's ok. But everything is more crystal clear if you use the set definitions:

If $f : X \to Y$, and $A \subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$, then we define

$$f(A) := \{y \in Y \, : \,  y = f(x) \text{ and } x \in A\} $$

$$f^{-1}(B) := \{x \in X \, : \,  f(x) \in B \} $$

This way

$\subseteq$

\begin{align}
 b \in f(f^{-1}(B)) & \Rightarrow b \in  \{y \in Y \, : \,  y = f(x) \text{ and } x \in f^{-1}(B)\}\\
& \Rightarrow b = f(a), \text{ for some } a \in f^{-1}(B)\\
& \Rightarrow b = f(a), \text{ and } a \in \{x \in X \, : \,  f(x) \in B \}\\
& \Rightarrow b = f(a), \text{ and } f(a) \in B\\
& \Rightarrow b \in B.
\end{align}

$\supseteq$

\begin{align}
b \in B & \Rightarrow f(a) = b \text{ for some } a \in X \quad \text{(since }f \text{ is surjective)} \\
& \Rightarrow f(a) \in B \text{ and } a \in X\\
& \Rightarrow a \in f^{-1}(B)\\
& \Rightarrow f(a) \in f(f^{-1}(B)).\\
\end{align}

Comment: This made very much sense! Perhaps it's a very good idea to write out the definitions in this way, since I'm no genius. (I believe that I'm a very "visual" thinker - I'm not good at verbal instruction etc. - so perhaps I could learn mathematics by writing more? Math in high school and kindergarten was not very challenging to me, perhaps I'm a bit lazy in some way also. The text book is visual of course, but since I'm no genius perhaps I could manage it by writing out definitions in a more tedious way.)

Comment: Yeah, at least for me, writing the proofs in this way has helped me a lot to progress in general, because you know exactly every step of the proof